# v2p migration from microsoft virtual pc to a physical zotac mini using clonezilla possible?

Tags: virtual-machines

I want to migrate a microsoft virtual pc running windows xp to a zotac mini.
Anyone have any luck doing something like this with modified version of these [vmware v2p](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/doc/V2P_TechNote.pdf) instructions ?

I would prefer to stick to free tools like clonezilla, but can spend money if there is a nice ready made tool for this.

plan: 
install all zotac drivers into virtual machine.
boot into clonezilla on virtual machine, clone drive to image
boot image onto zotac, and hopefully the hardware will be reconfigured ?

any good instructions available on using sysprep ?

Answer (score 1):

I was successful following the directions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314082).  (linked from [virtual box](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows) p2v instructions).

I didn't use sysprep.

Then I was able to :

> mount the clonezilla iso in the virtual pc. 
>   mount a second virtual harddrive on virtual pc (fixed size).
>   format the second virtual harddrive to fat32.
>   boot into clonezilla and clone drive to image.
>   move image to physical pc.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is XP, you will need to be real careful about storage drivers.  That is my experience migrating images between *physical* computers, let alone V2P.  Good luck.  Your best bet is to Sysprep the machine and generalize it.  If you need help with Sysprep, let me know.

**EDIT:** So about the Sysprep nonsense.  Download [the tools], and there is a GUI utility, called [SetupMgr](http://www.petri.co.il/using_sysprep_in_an_image_based_installation.htm) that should walk you through the tedious, wonderful word of creating the appropriate answer file so it will seal your image and run it through the setup without needing to click buttons and do the normal crap.  Long story short, your two big concerns will be drivers (as you are well aware) and the license key you will use **after** you seal the image (it will be like a brand new Windows install, even if your not-so-brand-few files are on the inside).  That link to SetupMgr does a good overview of the process, and Petri stuff is awesome as far as to the point docs go.  Enjoy.